# Firebase realtime Android - how to handle callbacks that are called constantly

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code and as you can see I've added a delta time to avoid update the UI intensively.

How can I solve this problem in a fancy way?
Is there a way force a delay of addValueEventListener update lets say M miliseconds without my delta workarround?

```
val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("array_constantly_updated")
val delta = 1200L
var lastUpdate = 0L
db.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
    }
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis()-lastUpdate>=delta) {
            lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis()
        } else {
            return
        }
        //update UIView ...
        //update UIView 2 ...
        //update UIView 3 ...
        //update UIView 4 ...
        //update more views etc 
        //at some point is too much work for UI Thread
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can perform your transactions on a job using Coroutines.

```
val job = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
        // operation
}
delay(1300L) // delay a bit

// job.cancel() // cancels the job
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer by @snorlax is a great one.

```
    val job = Globalscope.launch(Dispathers.Default) {
        val db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("array_constantly_updated")
        val delta = 1200L
        var lastUpdate = 0L
        while (true) {
            db.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                }

                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        //USE THIS BLOCK FOR ANY UI STUFF ONLY
                        //update UIView ...
                        //update UIView 2 ...
                        //update UIView 3 ...
                        //update UIView 4 ...
                        //update more views etc 
                        //at some point is too much work for UI Thread    
                    }
                }
            }
                    delay (1200)
        }
    }
```

What this does is it keeps executing every 1200 milliseconds and there is no need to check if delta time. and if you want this to stop just use,

```
job?.cancel
```

This will clear the job and the code any more doesn't get executed in coroutine score which the GlobalScope.

Comment: Putting the call to addValueEventListener on a different coroutine will do nothing to change its behavior, as it's already asychronous.  Also, putting it in a while loop like this will not do what you expect, because it's registers a callback that gets invoked repeatedly over time with updates from the database - doing that more than once is not helpful (and will leak the listeners).  You're more likely to want to put the work of the callback in a coroutine to change its behavior.

Comment: Oh yessss. Thats right im definately wrong  :(  Thanks allot. And also happy that you had to comment on this one :)